# Determine ghostscript version

Tags: r

I once did a blog on combining graphis with external programs and received a terrific comment from a reader ([-click here-](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/08/splitting-and-combining-r-pdf-visuals/#comment-133)) on implementing this entirely within R with ghostscript as seen below.  I have been using this a bit lately and am wanting to share it with others.  I'd like to modify it to make the function more intuitive and detecting the ghostscript type is one mod I'd like to do but can't.  The unix vs. windows is easy via `.Platform`.  The sticking point is the windows 32 vs. 64 that I struggle with.

How can I use R to detect which ghostscript version (gswin32c or gswin64c) is running?  Merely looking at the computer's specifications isn't good enough because I run gswin32c on a Win 64 machine.  The idea is to remove the os argument entirely or set it to `NULL` and have the function try to access this information.

```
mergePDF <- function(infiles, outfile, os = "UNIX") {
    version <- switch(os,
        UNIX = "gs",
        Win32 = "gswin32c",
        Win64 = "gswin64c")
    pre = " -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="
    system(paste(paste(version, pre, outfile, sep = ""), infiles, collapse = " "))
}


pdf("file1.pdf", width = 10, height = 8)
plot(1:10, col="red", pch = 19)
dev.off()

pdf("file2.pdf", width = 16, height = 8)
plot(1:10)
dev.off()

mergePDF("file1.pdf file2.pdf", "mergefromR.pdf", "Win32")
```

Comment: Or copy what `compactPDF` does and use `Sys.getenv("R_GSCMD", "")`

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368147/iterate-interactively-many-plots-to-different-files/14368684#14368684

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tyler, dude. Have I been demoted from being a Stack Ove-***R***-flow peer to a "reader" of your blog? Or is that a promotion ;)

This feels a little hackish to me, but should get the job done. Add this as the first few lines of the function and remove the os argument:

```
testme <- c(UNIX = "gs -version", 
            Win32 = "gswin32c -version", 
            Win64 = "gswin64c -version")
os <- names(which(sapply(testme, system) == 0))
```

I've used the `-version` switch so that R doesn't try to load Ghostscript unnecessarily.

On my Ubuntu system, when I run this, `os` returns, as expected, `UNIX`, and on my Windows system where I have the 32-bit version of Ghostscript installed, it returns `Win32`. Try it out on your 64-bit machine running the 32-bit GS and let me know how it works.

---

#### Update

After reading the help pages for `system()` and `system2()`, I learned about `Sys.which()`, which seems to be exactly what you're looking for. Here it is in action on my Ubuntu system:

```
Sys.which(c("gs", "gswin32c", "gswin64c"))
#            gs      gswin32c      gswin64c 
# "/usr/bin/gs"            ""            "" 
names(which(Sys.which(c("gs", "gswin32c", "gswin64c")) != ""))
# [1] "gs"
```

Thus, OS specification can be skipped entirely in the `mergePDF()` function:

```
mergePDF <- function(infiles, outfile) {
  gsversion <- names(which(Sys.which(c("gs", "gswin32c", "gswin64c")) != ""))
  pre = " -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="
  system(paste(paste(gsversion, pre, outfile, sep = ""), infiles, collapse = " "))
}
```

You may want to do some error checking. If the length of `gsversion` is > 1 or is 0, for instance, you may want to stop the function and prompt the user to either install Ghostscript or to verify their Ghostscript version.

Comment: I sometimes fail to connect people.  That's funny :)  Still an awesome answer :)  If you're interested I've incorporated that answer plus yours here into a github package https://github.com/trinker/plotflow Thank you for your responses.  It's been great for the work flow.

Comment: @TylerRinker, no worries---I used to be "mrdwab" on here until I hit 10k and decided to switch to my real name. Not everyone has made that connection ;) I'll check out the package (correct link [here](https://github.com/trinker/plotflow)) soon.