# check if a program is installed

Tags: r, pandoc

I'm writing a function that uses pandoc in R through the command line.  How can I use R to check if pandoc installed (I also assume it would have to be on the path which may be an issue for windows users)?

Comment: Testing both solutions on windows computers that had pandoc and didn't have pandoc... it looks like both work.  I don't know which solution is more robust though.

Comment: One advantage I can see of the `system('pandoc - v')` approach over `Sys.which` is that it verifies that the program is not only installed, but can actually be run.

Comment: @BrianDiggs brilliant !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This suggestion is based entirely on my personal experience with this question that RStudio can't seem to read what's in my `.bashrc` file on my Ubuntu system. I have installed Pandoc using the `cabal install pandoc` method described [here](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html) since there were features I needed from more recent versions of Pandoc than were available with Ubuntu's package manager. Running R from the terminal could detect Pandoc as expected using `Sys.which`, but when using RStudio, it could not. *I have no idea if this is a problem with Windows users or not though!*

One alternative/workaround in this case is actually creating a vector of typical paths where you expect the Pandoc executable to be found (under the presumption that many users don't really futz around with *where* they install programs). This info is, again, available at the install page linked above, plus the typical `C:\\PROGRA~1\\...` path for Windows. Thus, you might have something like the following as the paths to Pandoc:

```
myPaths <- c("pandoc", 
             "~/.cabal/bin/pandoc", 
             "~/Library/Haskell/bin/pandoc", 
             "C:\\PROGRA~1\\Pandoc\\bin\\pandoc") 
             # Maybe a .exe is required for that last one?
             # Don't think so, but not a regular Windows user
```

Which you can use with `Sys.which()` (for example, `Sys.which(myPaths)`) and some of the other ideas already shared.

- If the first option is uniquely matched, then there's no problem: you can use system calls to Pandoc directly.
- If any of the other options are uniquely matched, you can write your functions in such a way that you paste in the full path to the executable in your system call instead of just "pandoc".
- If the first option and any of the other options are matched, then you can just select the first option and proceed.
- If none are matched, prompt the user for the path to their Pandoc installation or provide a message on how to install Pandoc.

Comment: this approach works and doesn't require the user to reconfigure things.  Worked both on Linux and Windows +1  You didn't give me what I asked for you figured out what I needed.

Comment: @agstudy, you're welcome. Both your and Dason's answers were actually the first that came to mind (I had made the same suggestions to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14376517/1270695)) but when I tried it out before posting my answer, it didn't work, hence my need to dig a little further ;)

Answer (score 13):

I don't have pandoc to install , but generally I test if a program is installed like this :

```
pandoc.installed <- system('pandoc -v')==0
```

For example to test if java is installed:

```
 java.installed <- system('java -version') ==0

java version "1.7.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
> java.installed
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: you solution was exactly what I asked for thank you.  Ananda figured out what I actually needed when i didn't know I needed it.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you could use `Sys.which` and see if the result is an empty string.

```
pandoc.location <- Sys.which("pandoc")
if(pandoc.location == ""){
    print("pandoc not available")
}else{
    print("pandoc available")
}
```

Comment: This works on my Windows box but `Sys.which("firefox")` returns `""`, but `system("open firefox")` launches a Firefox browser... I wonder why.

Comment: Would have been my suggestion too (I also suggested it to Tyler for Ghostscript [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14376517/1270695)), but it doesn't work on my system for some reason. Perhaps because it was a cabal install? But not sure...

Comment: Good point.  I haven't really tested this on windows.  I'm wondering if pandoc might be a little different though since it's mainly a command line utility

Comment: Alright I just gave this a try on my windows box that has pandoc installed and it worked

Comment: @Dason, on my Ubuntu system, I can get the path if I run R from the terminal, but not if I run it from RStudio--seems like RStudio isn't seeing what's in my `.bashrc` file. For that matter, `system("pandoc -v")` doesn't work from within RStudio with my current setup either. Hmm...

Comment: @AnandaMahto Which version of Ubuntu are you using?  I'm on 12.04 and it's working from RStudio for me.  Which version of RStudio?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04, RStudio 0.97.307, and pandoc a little out of date at 1.9.4.5

Comment: I just checked and yeah it looks like RStudio isn't reading .bashrc.  I'm using the really old version of pandoc from the repositories so it's in /usr/bin which RStudio is happy with.  Maybe we should let RStudio know about this difference...

Comment: @AnandaMahto I found a solution/workaround to our shared problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14971110/1003565)

Comment: @Dason your solution works but requires the user to mess with stuff (which they may want to do) but Ananda's solution doesn't require the user to alter anything.  See: https://github.com/trinker/reports/blob/master/R/html5.R

Comment: @TylerRinker I know - and I mention that in the comments to my solution over there.  My solution is nice but for deployment for a general 'user' Ananda's solution is preferable.  But just to solve the issue that arises of RStudio not recognizing the path to pandoc... my solution works well.