# system open RStudio close connection

Tags: r

I'm attempting to use R to open a .Rproj file used in RStudio.  I have succeeded with the code below (stolen from [Ananda here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14971683/1000343)).   However, the connection to open RStudio called from R is not closed after the file is opened.  **How can I sever this "connection" after the .Rproj file is opened?** (PS this has not been tested on Linux or Mac yet).

```
## Create dummy .Rproj
x <- c("Version: 1.0", "", "RestoreWorkspace: Default", "SaveWorkspace: Default", 
    "AlwaysSaveHistory: Default", "", "EnableCodeIndexing: Yes", 
    "UseSpacesForTab: No", "NumSpacesForTab: 4", "Encoding: UTF-8", 
    "", "RnwWeave: knitr", "LaTeX: pdfLaTeX")

loc <- file.path(getwd(), "Bar.rproj")
cat(paste(x, collapse = "\n"), file = loc)

## wheresRStudio function to find RStudio location 
wheresRstudio <- 
function() {
    myPaths <- c("rstudio",  "~/.cabal/bin/rstudio", 
        "~/Library/Haskell/bin/rstudio", "C:\\PROGRA~1\\RStudio\\bin\\rstudio.exe",
        "C:\\RStudio\\bin\\rstudio.exe")
    panloc <- Sys.which(myPaths)
    temp <- panloc[panloc != ""]
    if (identical(names(temp), character(0))) {
        ans <- readline("RStudio not installed in one of the typical locations.\n 
            Do you know where RStudio is installed? (y/n) ")
        if (ans == "y") {
                temp <- readline("Enter the (unquoted) path to RStudio: ")
        } else {
            if (ans == "n") {
                stop("RStudio not installed or not found.")
            }
        }
    } 
    temp
}

## function to open .Rproj files
open_project <- function(Rproj.loc) {
    action <- paste(wheresRstudio(), Rproj.loc)
    message("Preparing to open project!")
    system(action)
}


## Test it (it works but does no close)
open_project(loc)
```

Comment: Downvoter care to share why so I can improve the question?

Comment: Have you tried `closeAllConnections()`?

Comment: @Roman Normally this might work but this usage is for use in a package and I remember once Yihui stating it was bad to use `closeAllConnections` as you don't know what other connections in other packages it may close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do exactly. What you've described doesn't really sound to me like a "connection" -- it's a `system` call.

I *think* what you're getting at is that after you run `open_project(loc)` in your above example, you don't get your R prompt back until you close the instance of RStudio that was opened by your function. If that is the case, you should add `wait = FALSE` to your `system` call.

You might also need to add an `ignore.stderr = TRUE` in there to get directly back to the prompt. I got some error about "QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method" on my Ubuntu system, and after I hit "enter" it took me back to the prompt. `ignore.stderr` can bypass that (but might also mean that the user doesn't get meaningful errors in the case of serious errors).

In other words, I would change your `open_project()` function to the following and see if it does what you expect:

```
open_project <- function(Rproj.loc) {
    action <- paste(wheresRstudio(), Rproj.loc)
    message("Preparing to open project!")
    system(action, wait = FALSE, ignore.stderr = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Precisely what I was after.  Thanks yet again.

Comment: Note that all `wait = FALSE` does is add `&` to the end of your command.