# Running R with Linux Mint

Tags: linux, r

I recently obtained a laptop computer running `Linux Mint 17`.  I have never previously used a computer that ran `Linux` (except when submitting `R` files to a cluster).

I would like to install `R` on the laptop.  The options presented at http://cran.at.r-project.org/
seem to be:

```
1. debian
2. redhat
3. suse
4. ubuntu
```

I suspect these are different variations of `Linux`.  Which of these is appropriate for a machine running `Linus Mint`?

If I click on the terminal icon on my laptop and type:

```
mark@mark-Vostro-1500 ~ $ lsb_release -irc
```

I get:

```
Distributor ID: LinusMint
Release: 17
Codename: qiana
```

A start-up screen also includes the term: `Cinnamon 32-bit`

I think from this post:

[R doesn't recognize Pandoc Linux Mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968103/r-doesnt-recognize-pandoc-linux-mint)

that `Linus Mint` will run `R`, but I do not know which of the four options I need.  Perhaps any of the four options will work?

Thank you for any advice and sorry for such a basic question.

Comment: Mint is basing on Ubuntu. Using option 4 will be fine.

Comment: @Yuan Thank you.  If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mint is basing on Ubuntu. Using option 4 will be fine.

You can check on this page http://www.linuxmint.com/about.php

> - Based on Debian and Ubuntu, it provides about 30,000 packages and one
>     of the best software managers.

Actually, it uses basic apt repositories from Ubuntu. Using apt to install the packages is fine, as mentioned by jms.

Comment: Also worthwhile to add that Qiana corresponds to Ubuntu's Trusty release. Not specific to R, but for a new Mint user you're bound to come across this at some point.

Answer (score 5):

Open terminal window and type the following to install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Provide your password and confirm the installation with 'y'.

To start the R: make a work directory, change into it and type 'R':

```
$ mkdir my_work
$ cd my_work
$ R
```

Comment: This answer was very helpful also deserves a check mark.