# How do I test if system executable is present within R

Tags: r, system

Suppose I need to run a system executable (`myexecutable`) file within R. I want to print a message "Please install myexecutable to run this proprogram" if it is not installed. How do I do it in R?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964457/check-if-a-program-is-installed

Comment: Only that the duplicate does not (sufficiently) feature `Sys.which()` which is _the_ command for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Sys.which()`.

#### Worked example

```
R> testForMyProg <- function(prg) { if (Sys.which(prg) == "") message("Please install ", prg) }
R> testForMyProg("lalalalaNope")
Please install lalalalaNope
R> testForMyProg("gcc")
R> 
R>
```