# Merging existing PDF files using R

Tags: r, pdf

I want to merge PDF files that already exist (already saved in my computer) using R.

I already tried to use open source softwares to merge them and it works fine but since I have a couple hundreds of files to merge together, I was hoping to find something a little faster (my goal is to have the file automatically created - or updated, simply by running an R command).

I am used to R so I would like to find a way to create this new multiple-sheet PDF using this program. Is there any function that could do that for me?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're on linux, I would suggest using `pdftk` from the command line.  You can write yourself a script in `R` using `?system` to call out to it directly.

Comment: Echoing @Justin's comment, see [this Q&A on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14366406/1270695) and the [related blog post](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/08/splitting-and-combining-r-pdf-visuals/#comment-133). Requires "ghostscript" so should work on any platform.

Comment: Thank you both for answering, I'll try it with 'gostscript'. (I'm not on linux, so 'pdftk' doesn't work for me)

Comment: There is pdftk for Windows and OSX http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit

Answer (score 27):

For an R-based solution which *doesn't* rely on calling the underlying OS with
`system()` or `system2()`, I would recommend the [{qpdf}
package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qpdf/qpdf.pdf).

You may install this package as:

```r
install.packages("qpdf")
```

You'll then want to make use of the `pdf_combine()` function. Check its
documentation as:

```r
?qpdf::pdf_combine
```

You can then merge as many pdfs as you like. Here I merge `file.pdf`,
`file2.pdf` and `file3.pdf` into a new file called `output.pdf`:

```r
qpdf::pdf_combine(input = c("file.pdf", "file2.pdf", "file3.pdf"),
                  output = "output.pdf")
```

Comment: Are fillable PDF forms compatible with this function?

Comment: @SourceCoda I do not know. I'd suggest giving it a go and seeing.

Answer (score 2):

If you install `pdftk` (found [here](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit)), then you can use the function below:

```
concatenate_pdfs <- function(input_filepaths, output_filepath) {
  # Take the filepath arguments and format them for use in a system command
  quoted_names <- paste0('"', input_filepaths, '"')
  file_list <- paste(quoted_names, collapse = " ")
  output_filepath <- paste0('"', output_filepath, '"')
  # Construct a system command to pdftk
  system_command <- paste("pdftk",
                          file_list,
                          "cat",
                          "output",
                          output_filepath,
                          sep = " ")
  # Invoke the command
  system(command = system_command)
}
```

Which could be called as follows:

```
concatenate_pdfs(input_filepaths = c("My First File.pdf", "My Second File.pdf"),
                 output_filepath = "My Combined File.pdf")
```

This is just a user-friendly way of invoking the following system command:

```
pdftk "My First File.pdf" "My Second File.pdf" cat output "My Combined File.pdf"
```