# Combine pdfs using R

Tags: r, pdf

I would like to combine the pages of many pdfs in a single pdf file. I know the names of the pdfs and the page numbers. E.g.,

```
pdf_frame=data.frame(pdf=c("pdf1", "pdf1", "pdf2"), pages=c(1,10,30))
```

Is there any way that I merge these pages of the pdfs to a single pdf using R? I would also be open to python.

Best
Alex

Comment: There is a package on CRAN called `pdftools` that sounds promising based on it's description, but I haven't used it.

Comment: Are these existing PDFs or graph output from R? If the latter, it's possible to create one PDF by sending multiple plots to the pdf device.

Comment: These are existing PDFs

Comment: What's your system? Are you using Windows?

Comment: See the answer given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552917/merging-existing-pdf-files-using-r/45467602#45467602