# Merge multiple pdf file in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a package in order to merge pdf files and add within each merged file a title in the top-left corner to recognize that file.

Does someone know a package that can do that ?

I would need to merge a list of pdf within a directory, and then add in the top-left a text with a specific text I'll choose (for example the name of the pdf file).

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552917/merging-existing-pdf-files-using-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging existing PDF files using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552917/merging-existing-pdf-files-using-r)

Comment: Hi, no since I need to write a title for each merged pdf..

Answer (score 1):

**1) pdftk** Make sure you have latex and [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) installed and that `pdflatex` and `pdftk` are on your PATH. I used `pdftk 2.02` below.

First define `filenames` (see Note at end for some test files) and make sure that the current directory is writeable and it contains the files.

Use `ani.options` from animation package to specify that `pdftk` is on your path.

Then loop through filenames generating a `*-stamp.pdf` file for each that consists only of a header and use the `pdftk stamp` command to merge it with the input file to produce a `*-hdr.pdf` file that is the input file with the header.

Finally use `pdftk cat` command to merge all the `*-hdr.pdf` files creating `all.pdf`.

If you are not using Windows replace the `shell` command with a `system` command.

```
# see Note at the end for a test setup
library(animation)
ani.options(pdftk = "pdftk") 

fmt <- r"(\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{%s}
\begin{document}
\null
\end{document})"

# for each file create a -stamp.pdf file with just the header and then use 
# pdftk stamp to superimpose it on the input file creating a -hdr.pdf file
for(f in filenames) {
  cat("...", f, "\n")
  # generate stamp file
  stamp.tex <- sub("\\.pdf$", "-stamp.tex", f)
  cat(sprintf(fmt, f), file = stamp.tex)
  cmd <- paste("pdflatex", stamp.tex)
  shell(cmd)

  # stamp f with stamp file
  stamp.pdf <- sub("\\.pdf$", "-stamp.pdf", f) # stamp
  f.hdr <- sub("\\.pdf$", "-hdr.pdf", f) # version of f with header
  pdftk(f, paste("stamp", stamp.pdf), f.hdr)
}

filenames.hdr <- sub("\\.pdf$", "-hdr.pdf", filenames)
pdftk(filenames.hdr, "cat", "all.pdf", "")
```

**2) qpdf** An alternative to pdftk is to use qpdf.  This has the advantage that qpdf is an R package and no external utilities are needed other than latex/pdflatex (which you may already have anyways).  The code is nearly the same.

```
# see Note at the end for a test setup
library(qpdf)

fmt <- r"(\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{%s}
\begin{document}
\null
\end{document})"

# for each file create a -stamp.pdf file with just the header and then use 
# pdf_overlay_stamp to superimpose it on input file creating *-hdr.pdf
for(f in filenames) {
  cat("...", f, "\n")
  # generate stamp file
  stamp.tex <- sub("\\.pdf$", "-stamp.tex", f)
  cat(sprintf(fmt, f), file = stamp.tex)
  cmd <- paste("pdflatex", stamp.tex)
  shell(cmd)

  # stamp f with stamp file
  stamp.pdf <- sub("\\.pdf$", "-stamp.pdf", f) # stamp
  f.hdr <- sub("\\.pdf$", "-hdr.pdf", f) # version of f with header
  pdf_overlay_stamp(f, stamp.pdf, f.hdr)
}

filenames.hdr <- sub("\\.pdf$", "-hdr.pdf", filenames)
pdf_combine(filenames.hdr, "all.pdf")
```

**3) qpdf without latex** This is a variation of (2) that uses the grid package to eliminate the need for all external utilities including latex.  The grid package comes pre-installed with R so it does not have to be installed -- only loaded with a `library` statement. The code is quite close to (2).

```
library(grid)
library(qpdf)

# for each file create a -stamp.pdf file with just the header and then use 
# pdf_overlay_stamp to superimpose it on input file creating *-hdr.pdf
for(f in filenames) {
  cat("...", f, "\n")
  # generate stamp file
  stamp.pdf <- sub("\\.pdf$", "-stamp.pdf", f)
  pdf(stamp.pdf, height = 11.0, width = 8.5)
  grid.text(f, 0.03, 0.98, just = "left", gp = gpar(fontsize = 12))
  dev.off()

  # stamp f with stamp file
  f.hdr <- sub("\\.pdf$", "-hdr.pdf", f) # version of f with header
  pdf_overlay_stamp(f, stamp.pdf, f.hdr)
}

filenames.hdr <- sub("\\.pdf$", "-hdr.pdf", filenames)
pdf_combine(filenames.hdr, "all.pdf")
```

### Note

Generate test files

```
library(zoo)
# setwd("~/../Downloads") # cd to a writeable directory

filenames <- c("zoo.pdf", "zoo-faq.pdf")
for(f in filenames) {
  file.copy(system.file("doc", f, package = "zoo"), f)
}
```