# Write existing PDFs to file alongside dynamic plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

The project I'm working on has a somewhat odd requirement: a text description of some data, sourced from a TeX-based PDF file, should appear in the middle of a series of normal plots produced by ggplot2. Each plot should be on its own page:

```
pdf("output.pdf")
ggplot(<complicated plot>)
duplicate.pdf("description.pdf")   # problematic line
ggplot(<another plot>)
```

However, while I can find countless packages which allow me to read PDFs' contents, convert them to images and otherwise alter them, I'm struggling to find something which will simply allow me to copy a PDF, unchanged. 
What I'm looking for is something similar to command-line tools such as **pdftk .. cat ..**.

So, the question is simple: how do I read in and read out an external PDF in the middle of an R script?

Comment: Make separate plots as pdfs, then call pdftk to merge them, see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366406/determine-ghostscript-version)